# Mocking method with Action<T> parameter

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asynchronous

[unit testing newbie] [c#]

Consider the following scenario:

**I'm using Silverlight and calling a WCF service. Silverlight can only call WCF services asynchronously.** I build a wrapper around the WCF service so that I can work with Action parameters. (makes the client code a lot cleaner).

So I have an async service that retrieves meeting rooms.

```
public interface IMeetingRoomService
{
    void GetRooms(Action<List<MeetingRoom>> result);
}
```

Turning GetRooms into `List<MeetingRoom> GetRooms()` is not an option.

I want to use this service in a ViewModel to set a public property called Rooms.

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    private readonly IMeetingRoomService _meetingRoomService;

    public List<MeetingRoom> Rooms { get; set; }

    public SomeViewModel(IMeetingRoomService meetingRoomService)
    {
        this._meetingRoomService = meetingRoomService;
    }

    public void GetRooms()
    {
        // Code that calls the service and sets this.Rooms
        _meetingRoomService.GetRooms(result => Rooms = result);
    }
}
```

I want to unit test the implementation of SomeViewModel.GetRooms().
(For this question I quickly wrote the implementation but I'm actually trying to use TDD.)

How do I finish this test? 
I'm using NUnit and Moq.

```
[Test]
public void GetRooms_ShouldSetRooms()
{
    var theRooms = new List<MeetingRoom>
                       {
                           new MeetingRoom(1, "some room"),
                           new MeetingRoom(2, "some other room"),
                       };

    var meetingRoomService = new Mock<IMeetingRoomService>();

    //How do I setup meetingRoomService so that it gives theRooms in the Action??


    var viewModel = new SomeViewModel(meetingRoomService.Object);

    viewModel.GetRooms();

    Assert.AreEqual(theRooms, viewModel .Rooms);
}
```

EDIT:

**Solution**

Read Stephane's answer first.

This is the Test code I ended up writing thanks to stephane's answer:

```
[Test]
public void GetRooms_ShouldSetRooms()
{
    var meetingRoomService = new Mock<IMeetingRoomService>();
    var shell = new ShellViewModel(meetingRoomService.Object);
    var theRooms = new List<MeetingRoom>
                       {
                           new MeetingRoom(1, "some room"),
                           new MeetingRoom(2, "some other room"),
                       };

    meetingRoomService
        .Setup(service => service.GetRooms(It.IsAny<Action<List<MeetingRoom>>>()))
        .Callback((Action<List<MeetingRoom>> action) => action(theRooms));

    shell.GetRooms();

    Assert.AreEqual(theRooms, shell.Rooms);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is some pseudo code, I haven't run it. But I think that's what you want.

SetupCallback is what you are interested in.

For all the calls to _meetingRoomServiceFake.GetRooms, simply set the _getRoomsCallback to the parameter passed in.

You now have a reference to the callback that you are passing in your viewmodel, and you can call it with whatever list of MeetingRooms you want to test it.
So you can test your asynchronous code almost the same way as synchronous code. it's just a bit more ceremony to setup the fake.

```
Action<List<MeetingRoom>> _getRoomsCallback = null;
IMeetingRoomService _meetingRoomServiceFake;


private void SetupCallback()
{
     Mock.Get(_meetingRoomServiceFake)
         .Setup(f => f.GetRooms(It.IsAny<Action<List<MeetingRoom>>>()))
         .Callback((Action<List<MeetingRoom>> cb) => _getRoomsCallback= cb);
}

[Setup]
public void Setup()
{
     _meetingRoomServiceFake = Mock.Of<IMeetingRoomService>();
     SetupCallback();
}

[Test]
public void Test()
{

      var viewModel = new SomeViewModel(_meetingRoomServiceFake)

      //in there the mock gets called and sets the _getRoomsCallback field.
      viewModel.GetRooms();
      var theRooms = new List<MeetingRoom>
                   {
                       new MeetingRoom(1, "some room"),
                       new MeetingRoom(2, "some other room"),
                   };

     //this will call whatever was passed as callback in your viewModel.
     _getRoomsCallback(theRooms);
}
```

Comment: Amazing, it works! I don't understand it completely, but it does work. I had to set _getRoomsCallBack to null or the code wouldn't compile. And FYI without implementation this test threw a nullreference exception on this line: "getRoomsCallback(theRooms);" because the callback was still null

Comment: I will add details to explain :)

Comment: Okay I understand it now, thanks to your 2 well placed lines of comment. Thanks a lot, this was very helpful! But feel free to add more details, because I only understand it to a certain level :-)

Comment: Since I'm not using a setup method I found out I don't need the getCallbackRoom variable. See the solution I used, posted in my original question. The amount of code needed ends up being very small. Again, thanks!

Comment: yep, I put it in a variable because I usually have a test class that will test just this behaviour, so in the end, my actual test method are really just calling the method with different parameters, and asserting, leaving this complexity "hidden" in the Setup. But that works nicely too :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AutoResetEvent to handle async calls.

Just initialize it as unset and configure your mock service to set it in the callback. 
(IE: 
 var mockService = new Mock(); 
 mockService.SetUp(x => x.MyMethod()).Returns(someStuff).Callback(() => handle.Set());
)

After that I use hadle.WaitOne(1000) to check if it was called. (IMHO 1000 miliseconds are more than enough to run the async code).

Sorry: This was supposed to go as a reply to the post above... I can't for the life of me figure out how to reply :)